# script to show info in dwm status bar (e.g. on brightness/volume change)

Tags: shell-script, arch-linux, dwm

I have a dwm status bar that has only few info piped into it (using a bash script):
Volume, Battery, Free Disk Space and Time.
Some things e.g. Volume and Brightness should only appear on change (vol up/down, brightness up/down).
I can do the following in a terminal:

```
vol="$(amixer get Master | tail -n1 | sed -r 's/.*\[(.*)%\].*/\1/')"  
printf '%s\n' "Volume set to ${vol}" | dzen2 -p 3
```

which makes dzen show the actual volume in the middle of the bar (same works with brightness).

I use XF86MonBrightnessDown XF86MonBrightnessUp (defined in config.h) to alter brightness.
How can I get this info on vol/brightness change?

Thanks for helping!

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly, you want to see a `dzen2` pop up when you change brightness/volume. You can do that from a script and trigger it when you press keys for same (`XF86MonBrightnessUp`, `XF86XK_AudioLowerVolume` etc).

Your dwm's `config.h` would have this line

```c
...
    { 0,        XF86XK_AudioRaiseVolume,    spawn,      SHCMD("volume_change.sh -i") },
    { 0,        XF86XK_AudioLowerVolume,    spawn,      SHCMD("volume_change.sh -d") },
...
```

The `SHCMD` command will run the given shell command. You can have a `volume_change.sh` script as

```bsh
#!/bin/sh

case $1 in

# Increase volume
    -i)
        pactl set-sink-volume @DEFAULT_SINK@ +5%
        vol="$(amixer get Master | tail -n1 | sed -r 's/.*\[(.*)%\].*/\1/')"  
        printf '%s\n' "Volume set to ${vol}" | dzen2 -p 3  
        ;;

# Decrease volume.
    -d)
        pactl set-sink-volume @DEFAULT_SINK@ -5%
        vol="$(amixer get Master | tail -n1 | sed -r 's/.*\[(.*)%\].*/\1/')"  
        printf '%s\n' "Volume set to ${vol}" | dzen2 -p 3  
    ;;
esac
```

And a similar script for brightness keys.

Make sure you have `volume_change.sh` in your `PATH` and it's executable.

Answer (score 0):

brightness:

```
xsetroot -name " $(expr $(cat /sys/class/backlight/intel_backlight/brightness) / 49)"
```

volume:

```
xsetroot -name "奄 $(pactl list sinks | grep '^[[:space:]]Volume:' | head -n $(( $SINK + 1 )) | tail -n 1 | sed -e 's,.* \([0-9][0-9]*\)%.*,\1,')%"
```

my dotfiles:

https://github.com/felipefacundes/dotfiles/tree/master/config/dwm

Do not copy and paste from here, because I noticed that in the post this site suppresses * invalidating the regular expression of the command, go to my dotfiles and get the script (barcomplete.sh)